# Integrating Flurry AppCircle Clips

Tags: iphone, analytics, ads, flurry

I've integrated Flurry Analytics and now am trying to add Flurry AppCircle Clips, but the AppCircle docs only seem to pertain to banners.

I'm looking for full screen ads or video ads to display at key times during my app's usage and would like to see documentation of how to implement such.

Has anyone any examples of creating a full-screen AppCircle Clip?

Comment: I've also sent an inquiry to Flurry and will post an example, should they provide one I'm able to successfully implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Flurry SDK (3.0.3), after including all the proper header files...

Include the FlurryAdDelegate protocol:

```
// MyAppDelegate.h
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <FlurryAdDelegate> {
    // ...
}
```

Setup Flurry Analytics and AppCircle:
(Not sure why the delegate-setting redundancy, but it didn't seem to work with only setting the protocol.)

```
// MyAppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleEnabled:YES];
    [FlurryClips setVideoAdsEnabled:YES];
    [FlurryAppCircle setAppCircleDelegate:self];
    [FlurryAnalytics startSession:@"AWWWTH36PXLU6Y3DN3GB"];

    // rest of my code ...
}
```

Then in my custom UIView class: (Again, after including all the proper header files)

```
// MyCustomView.m
[FlurryClips videoAdIsAvailable:@"VIDEO_SPLASH_HOOK"];
[FlurryClips openVideoTakeover:@"VIDEO_SPLASH_HOOK"
                   orientation:@"portrait"
                   rewardImage:nil
                 rewardMessage:nil
                   userCookies:nil
                      autoPlay:YES];
```

Also be sure to `#import` MediaPlayer.h in the appropriate view. (I think I read this somewhere in some version of the Flurry docs, but can't find it now... Doesn't help that the PDFs have a funny character encoding and are thus non-indexable).

I'd host the AppCircle-Clips docs they sent me, but am not sure if they'd approve, since they don't seem to have these available on the downloaded SDK. (Perhaps, because it won't let me download the 3.1 for my project?)

For further AppCircle-Clips-related questions, you can also email appcircleclips@flurry.com

Answer (score 1):

AppCircle provides openTakeover which you can take advantage, here is an example call:

```
[FlurryAppCircle openTakeover:@"my_hook_name" orientation:orientationString
    rewardImage:rewardImage rewardMessage:rewardString userCookies:nil];
```

Mike
Partner Integration, Flurry

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Someone from Flurry replied with detailed instructions. I'm waiting for an official link to the Clips-specific instructions and will post it here for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 0):

First, I must apologize for this thread.

And I show my reason.

My project encountered same problem with @Old McStopher.And I asked my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353066/how-does-flurry-appcircle-clips-work)

Unfortunately, nobody give us a correct answer.
The only hope about this question is the post which @Old McStopher posted -- "Thanks, Mike. Someone from Flurry replied with detailed instructions. I'm waiting for an official link to the Clips-specific instructions and will post it here for anyone else interested."

I really really need this implement for my project.I hope @Old McStopher could post his solve.
But I do NOT know how to contact @Old McStopher.

Apologize again.